# How to deal with the color profile while reading image using java

Tags: java, image, jpeg, rgb, jai

I find that while reading images(JPEG) using Java, the lots of pixels' RGB values are different with those in photoshop, the RGB values got by JIMI are also different with ImageIO, how can I get the RGB values exactly the same with photoshop in java ? thanks!

This is how I read images by:
1.ImageIO

`BufferedImage test = ImageIO.read(file);`
2.Jimi

`JimiReader createJimiReader = Jimi.createJimiReader(new FileInputStream(filename));`
`JimiRasterImage rasterImage = createJimiReader.getRasterImage();`

3.JAI

`FileSeekableStream st = new FileSeekableStream(filename);`
`BufferedImage asBufferedImage = JAI.create("stream", st).getAsBufferedImage();`

Comment: How do you read the images? How do you get the pixels? I can think of at least two very different reading methods and countless ways to get a pixel RGB...

Comment: Can you give me some details? thanks! I have tried to use ImageIO, JIMI, JAI.. JIMI and JAI will get the same result(still different with photoshop) , but ImageIO doesn't.

Comment: This is how I read images:
`BufferedImage test = ImageIO.read(file);`

`JimiReader createJimiReader = Jimi.createJimiReader(new FileInputStream(filename));`
`JimiRasterImage rasterImage = createJimiReader.getRasterImage();`

`FileSeekableStream st = new FileSeekableStream(filename);`
`BufferedImage asBufferedImage = JAI.create("stream", st).getAsBufferedImage();`

Comment: @ygnhzeus could you put that into your question? Nicely formatted of course ;)